# setting data with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, render, vue.js

Sorry for my begginner question, but I'm stucked since yesterday on a basic problem which i cannot figure out the solution.

I want to fill my variable logs with some json object and render it in an array.

Here is my html :

```
<tbody>

  <tr v-for="log in logs">
    <td>{{log.incident}}</td>
    <td>{{log.request}}</td>
    <td>{{log.requested}}</td>
    <td>{{log.message}}</td>               
  </tr>            

</tbody>
```

and here is my JS

```
let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#container',
    components: {
        'table-header': tableHeader,
    },
    data: {
        logs: []
    },
    methods: {
        getLogs() {
            addon.port.on('log', function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               this.$add('logs',data)
            });
        }
    },
    ready:{
        function(){this.getLogs()}
    }

});

vm.getLogs();
```

1. The ready does not seems to work. Why?
2. The this.logs is undefined? Why?
3. It complains that the "this.$add is not a function"
4. In the html the logs are never populated in the loop. why?

Comment: Check what vue version you have. In v2 they replaced 'ready' with 'mounted'

Comment: Please let us know, what VueJS version you are using.

Comment: I use the version 2.0.3.
Okey it works now with the mount

Comment: here is the code inside
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=gIQLorBo7t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `mounted`, something like:

```
mounted () {
    this.getLogs()    
}
```

[Documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/#mounted).

---

[data must be a function](https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) for a Vue component, but for a Vue instance it should be fine..

So for a Vue component, it should have data like following:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    logs : []
  }
}
```

Comment: data should not be function if it's not part of component .If it's part of components It should be function that return object.

Comment: @thiebautfischer yes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your ready should not be an object, it should be a function

2&3&4. Inside an anonymous function, `this` refers to something else.  Use an arrow function to keep the scope of `this`, or store a reference to `this`

```js
let vm = new Vue({
     el: '#container',
     components: {
         'table-header': tableHeader,
     },
     data: {
         logs: []
     },
     methods: {
         getLogs() {
             addon.port.on('log', (data) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.$add('logs',data)
             });
         }
     },
     ready() {
         this.getLogs()
     }

     });
```

```js
//OR do this
getLogs() {
  var that = this;
             addon.port.on('log', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                that.$add('logs',data)
             });
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your example is valid and I can't test it at the moment but I am used to the syntax like so:

```
ready: function(){
    console.log('ready);
}
```

Same goes for your methods. Maybe check the documentation and apply the syntax like given there to begin with.

https://vuejs.org/guide/index.html#Getting-Started

Comment: yes I tried this way but it does not work, it does not print ready

Comment: I did not find proper documentation about ready, but as far as I understood it is running the functions inside ready once the object is created?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could make a small example in JSfiddle.